# EmberJS and URL structure issues

Tags: url, design-patterns, ember.js, seo

We are using EmberJS for some sign up forms on our website. The sign up is for different sections of our offering. We should like the form to reflect the section, in the following URL pattern:

```
Http://domain.com/section1/signup/  
Http://domain.com/section2/signup/  
Http://domain.com/section3/signup/  
...
```

We want the signup form across these sections, around ten sections or so, to be the same Ember code but referring to ten config files.

The issue with this is that EmberJS would either require all the JS and assets to be in the root folder to achieve the architecture I describe above, or we would need multiple copies of the same Ember and assets in ten folders for each section.

Because ember wants the JS etc to be in the same location, ideally in root, I suppose the following is easy:

```
Http://domain.com/signup/section1/  
Http://domain.com/signup/section2/  
Http://domain.com/signup/section3/  
...
```

But this is not ideal for us given our URL pattern ambition. Both for human users and SEO purposes.

Is there something creative we can do to work around this Ember limitation? Something like URL rewriting or any other clever structuring of code. Welcome any thoughts from the gurus.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you could do something like
`this.route('section', {path:':section_name/sign-up'});` 
in your router, where 'section' would be your model (config).

Of course, you would need to create route 'section', appropriate template and check if passed parameter **':section_name'** is one of the allowed ones and than you should serve appropriate model / config file.